# Runtime error 424 Object required

Tags: vba, excel

I am unable to find my error in the sub listed below. I receive a "Runtime error 424 Object Required" message.

My intention is to convert my excel formula into VBA code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_INDEXMATCH()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set wb = Workbooks("WORKBOOK.xlsm")

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        SHEET1NAME.Range("E13") = _
        .Index(SHEET2NAME.Range("D:D"), .Match(lookup_value, SHEET1NAME.Range("B13"), 0), .Match(lookup_value, SHEET2NAME.Range("A:A"), 0))

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your code actually have `SHEET1NAME` or is that a placeholder? If it's a placeholder, are you literally just using the sheet name there? Because it should be `Sheets("Sheet1Name").Range("E13")`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're indexing in a single dimension array, it doesn't make sense to have two parameters for the `Index`.

```
.Index(SHEET2NAME.Range("D:D"), .Match(lookup_value, SHEET2NAME.Range("A:A"), 0))
```

Also,

> `.Match(lookup_value, SHEET1NAME.Range("B13"), 0)`

Doesn't make sense because you're searching in a single cell here. May be you meant to search in row 13?

```
.Match(lookup_value, SHEET1NAME.Range("13:13"), 0)
```

However, you would use 2 parameters for`Index` only if you're indexing in a two-dimensional range. but then you will need to invert the 2nd and 3rd parameters that you gave to `Index`, because the 2nd param is a row index, which is fetched in a column, and the 3rd is a column index fetched in the row.

For example, suppose you want to find a cell, in range `A1:D20` where `lookup_value` appears on column `A` (of the same row) and on row 13 (of the same column):

```
myVariable = .Index(SHEET2NAME.Range("D:D"), _
    .Match(lookup_value, SHEET2NAME.Range("A:A"), 0), _
    .Match(lookup_value, SHEET1NAME.Range("13:13"), 0))
```

By the way, what are `SHEET1NAME` and `SHEET2NAME`? just names or worksheet objects? All of the above supposed they are Worksheet objects, but I guess the runtime error is complaining that these are just names not objects! In this case, replace them everywhere with `Worksheets(SHEET1NAME)` and `Worksheets(SHEET2NAME)`.

Comment: My excel formula was...=INDEX(SHEET2NAME!D:D,MATCH($B$13, SHEET2NAME!$A:$A, 0))

Comment: B13 is on SHEET1NAME

Comment: @t.mo you can change the sheet's name part of the formula. i.e. `SHEET1NAME.Range("13:13")`. But you need to decide which param to use, you cant have 2 params to index in a single column.

Comment: by the way, what are `SHEET1NAME` and `SHEET2NAME`? just *names* or worksheet objects? I guiess the runtime error is complaining that these are just names not objects!

Comment: It's always **possible** that the sheets' `Name` and  `.CodeName` values are the same, but it may be safer to explicitly use `wb.Worksheets("SHEET1NAME").Range` instead of `SHEET1NAME.Range`.